# how do I list my keys in my mongodb database in one message (pymongo, discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, pymongo

I want to list my veriables and keys in one message?

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name="kayitsayi", description="Kayıt sayınızı gösterir")
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id=112233445566))
async def kayitsayi(ctx):
    for x in db.staffs.find_one({'guildID': ctx.guild.id}, {"_id": 0, "guildID": 0}):
        await ctx.reply(f"<@{x}>" + ": `" + str(db.staffs.find_one({'guildID': ctx.guild.id}, {"_id": 0, "guildID": 0})[x]) + "`")
```

I tried this but it sent keys and veriables one by one.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtKxE.png)

Comment: Use the loop to create a string and call `reply` **once** _after_ the loop?

Comment: how can i do that? I'm new at discord.py. @stijndcl

Comment: This isn't related to discord.py, that's just basic Python. You're already concatenating strings in your code fragment in the post, so it seems like you know everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this?

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name="kayitsayi", description="Kayıt sayınızı gösterir")
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id=112233445566))
async def kayitsayi(ctx):
    result = db.staffs.find_one({'guildID': ctx.guild.id}, {"_id": 0, "guildID": 0})
    message = ""
    for key, value in result.items():
        message += f"{key}: {value} "
    await ctx.reply(message)
```